# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting. Any help on how to fix this?

Tags: python, list, floating-point

I was trying out an interesting problem from *Code Arena* which was:

> You take 3 numbers N,D and R (where N is the numerator, D the denominator and R is the digit which you have to fetch after the decimal point). Suppose N=1, D=2 and R=20:
>
> So N/D=1/2=0.50000000000000000000. Here the 20th digit is 0.
>
> Again let N=1, D=2 and R=1. So N/D=1/2=0.5. Here the 1st digit is 5.

My code to find the solution for the above problem is:

```
l=[]
N,D,R=input().split()

x="%."+str(R)+"f"%(N/D)  #Used for storing the value of the decimal upto Rth digit

for j in str(x):         #Used to store all the values after the decimal point
    if j==".":
        for k in range(str(x).index(j)+1,len(str(x))):
            l.append(x[k])

print(l[len(l)-1])       #The last index of the list will have the required output
l=[]
```

But I keep getting the error `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting` in the line `x="%."+str(R)+"f"%(N/D)`. I've tried giving any random value like `x="%.2f"%(N/D)`, then it works.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```
N,D,R=input().split()

x= f'{float(N)/float(D):.{int(R)}f}'            #Used for storing the value of the decimal upto Rth digit

print(f"Answer = {x}")
print(f"Last digit = {x[-1]}")
```

Output:

```
>? 1 2 20
Answer = 0.50000000000000000000
Last digit = 0
```

```
>? 1 2 1
Answer = 0.5
Last digit = 5
```